# Counterpart of axis-angle rotation matrix in 4 dimensions?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, rotations, solid-geometry

In 3-dimensional space, we have an explicit formula for the rotation matrix which will rotate about a vector $\vec{a} = [a_x, a_y, a_z]$. This is given by:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\cos\theta+a_x^2(1-\cos\theta) & a_xa_y-a_z\sin\theta & a_xa_z(1-\cos\theta)+a_y \sin\theta \\
a_xa_y(1-\cos\theta)+a_z\sin\theta & \cos\theta+a_y^2(1-\cos\theta) & a_ya_z(1-\cos\theta)-a_x\sin\theta\\
a_xa_z(1-\cos\theta)-a_y\sin\theta & a_y a_z(1-\cos\theta)+a_x\sin\theta& \cos\theta+a_z^2(1-\cos\theta)
\end{bmatrix}
$$

In 4-d space, rotations are defined in a plane (in 3-d space as well, the rotation is happening in the plane orthogonal to the vector, $\vec{a}$).

Is there a corresponding formula that takes two vectors spanning the space that rotation is going to happen in (or the spanning the space which is going to be unaffected by the rotation) and the angle, $\theta$ we are going to rotate by as input and returns a $4 \times 4$ matrix?

Comment: But in $4$-space you can simultaneously rotate two orthogonal planes by arbitrary amounts. Or are you specifying that you fix the orthogonal $2$-plane? It's just a change of basis formula computation.

Comment: You should have a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotations_in_4-dimensional_Euclidean_space)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very good question! You may want to check out [Givens rotation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Givens_rotation) $G(i,j,\theta)$, which induces rotation of $\theta$ only in the plane defined by $i$ and $j$ axis of the space, with the orthongonal subspace unchanged.

If you do a basis change $P$ such that the first axes $1,2$ correspond to the vectors spanning the rotation plane you defined. Then this shall be the required rotation matrix
$$
PG(1,2,\theta)P^{-1}
$$

Comment: Thanks! Follow up: can every rotation in 4-d space be represented like this?